# How can I align <label>,<input>, text, input fields, a real button, and a "<a> link button" properly and with the same font?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

**MY PROBLEM (brief):**
I would like the text Username, the text you type for the Username, the Real Button Text the "or" and the Link Button Text to be exactly the same size and on the same "line" - they don't line up smoothly...

**HAVE I TRIED FIXING THIS MYSELF?  OTHER PROBLEMS WITH ZOOMING**
I've spent considerable time trying to get this aligned as close to perfect as I can get however, with my knowledge I can never get it lined up to satisfaction.  I gave up for many months while I worked on other parts of the website but it's a thorn in my mind that it SHOULD be possible.  I also had problems when I used scaling - in some zooms it looked so close to perfect I figured "That's as good as I can get it!".

I cut this out of my website to make the code as small as possible.  If you look at the result - the Username (the username you type), the "Real Button" and the "or" and the "Link Button" are all different heights... it doesn't seem to flow nicely.

Also, if you put the 2 buttons on top of each other the word SIGN is different widths.  If I'm using the same font, same size, same everything, why would 1 be wider than the other?  Different letter spacing?

While I did give up on this, recently I saw another fiddle from Stack that kinda solved the problem but without labels and without lining everything up.  THIS code is based on that code.  I figure, if this can be fixed, I'll re-work it into my website with all the responsive design etc...

**PREVIOUS PARTIAL SOLUTIONS:**
In the past I used tables and things seemed to line up better but I was trying not to use tables for this as you shouldn't have to create a table for such a short simple line of HTML.

**JSFIDDLE:**
I created a JSFiddle so you can see.

http://jsfiddle.net/PerryCS/7zc2vjmx/2/

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <form id="loginForm1" name="loginForm1?callingPage=validateForm" method="post" action="index.php" accept-charset="utf-8">

  <h5 class="text-center">In order to access some areas of the website, save estimates.</h5>

  <div class="mydiv">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <label for="pword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pword" name="pword">
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <input class="button" type="button" name="buttonSignIn" value="SIGN IN"> or
    <a class="button" href="#">SIGN UP</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input.button {
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #4D28B2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4D28B2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4D28B2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mydiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**MY THANKS FOR YOUR TIME**
I thank you in advance for your time in helping me grow these past few years.  You guys/gals have helped me solve some problems and your help is much appreciated.  :)

Comment: The button and input field heights look o.k. for me (in Chrome). You did not vertically align your labels, so do that as well. Only thing that’s left then that looks a little off, is the alignment of the text inside the input fields vs the text outside, text in the input fields seems placed a little higher. Changing the input field padding from `0px 5px` to `1px 5px 0px 5px` fixes that as well. That come closer to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/7zc2vjmx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a CSS rule for all these elements with identical settings and also add `vertical-align: baseline`. This should line up all text at the same baseline, and if the font-family, font-size, font-weight, font-variation etc. are the same, it should look as you want it.

For my fork of your fiddle I just added this (affecting all elements inside `.mydiv`):

```
.mydiv * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-family: Arial sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 1em !important;
}
```

Here's the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f03jvuqb/

Comment: Ah, never used !important before or baseline...   I'll merge the changes into my website and mark yours as the answer afterwards.  Thank you!   Going to have to see how I can get them lining up also since they all break at the div to the next line but that should be simple enough.  :)

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this totally valid question?   What may be easy for you, may not be easy to me.  I DID do research and got it very close, but I'm not an expert on CSS so I asked a question.  Wish people would at least say "WHY" they downvote you...  While there are similar questions on here, none of them were exactly this question...  Ah well, can't please everyone...

Comment: Hmm.... when I get them all on the same line (responsive breaking) - I keep

"Username and the input field together",
"Password and the input field together",
"Sign In or Sign Up together".

That's my 3 breakpoints.  When they line up, it goes all weird.  The 2 buttons drop WAY below baseline, the text in the label moves UP...

Can you show it on 1 line by floating them left and lining them up that way? (please)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, but in order tol line them up, what do you do? I made another fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/620ur600/) where I simply set `mydiv` to `display: inline;` in order to have everything in one line, and it still lines up properly, and also if I reduce the viewport width, the elements are distributed in several lines, but are still on the baseline.

Comment: Wow, that actually does work, in both browsers...   hmmm....  I must have some css interfering because yours works, mine doesn't when put into my actual website....   OK... thank you!  I'll mark it as answered.  Much appreciated.  

I should be able to figure out how to keep Username and the input field together, Password and it's input field together, and the 2 buttons together so it doesn't break in 7 spots but 3...

I have a feeling I don't fully understand what's going on.  Well, I'm happy your code is working.  That's all that matters.  :)

Comment: I realized something - when I put this in my real website it still doesn't line up.  So, I changed your fiddle to Verdana and it screws up again...   do you know why the other font would work, and Verdana would not work?  Verdana is my favorite font but if it's problematic should I stop using it?

http://jsfiddle.net/PerryCS/1odLzdjo/

Comment: your buttons  have `vertical-align: middle`. Erase that or change it to `vertical-align: baseline`

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with this and not being 100% happy with it... I looked into Flex Box which is quite popular now-a-days in most browsers.  Using Flex Box worked like a charm and the code was way cleaner.  Everything lined up beautifully and I was quite pleased with the results.  I learned a lot during all this tinkering.   I'll post the Flex Box code another day when I have more time.